# What are the tools/apps to plot all my client's shop on map and identify the center point (area with most shops) using "heatmap" visualization

Tags: web-apps, google-apps

I want to identify the most strategic / the nearest point that connects to all my client shops. Given that I have all the latitude and longitude of the shop, what tools can I use to plot all the shops on map and visualise the concentration of the shops using heatmap?

Comment: Welcome. Can you code? Are you looking for something to help you code this, or for a ready-made, off the shelf, solution?

Comment: Yes, I know python.. I am looking for tools that can display my coordinates and the concentration by area.

Comment: start at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSMPythonTools